# Read Chinese when export to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export

I am using oracle database and asp.net 2013..

code below is how I export my data from database to Excel file.

```
private DataTable GetData(string sqlcommand)
        {
            try
            { 
                string sapno = "SAP NO";
                string partno = "PART NO";
                string partdesc = "PART DESCRIPTION";
                string minQty = "MINIMUM QUANTITY";
                string QOH = "QUANTITY ON HAND";
                string category = "CATEGORY";
                string equipment = "EQUIPMENT";

                readdata.selectdata(ds, sqlcommand);
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
                dt.Columns[0].ColumnName = sapno;
                dt.Columns[1].ColumnName = partno;
                dt.Columns[2].ColumnName = partdesc;
                dt.Columns[3].ColumnName = minQty;
                dt.Columns[4].ColumnName = QOH;
                dt.Columns[5].ColumnName = category;
                dt.Columns[6].ColumnName = equipment;
                ds.Tables.Clear();
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            } 
        }

        protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the data from database into datatable
            string sqlcommand=null;

            if (validate.isEmpty(txtPartNo.Text) == true || Session["SAPNOIR"] ==null)
            {
                sqlcommand = "SELECT SAPNO , PARTNO, PARTDESC, MINQTY, QOH , CATEGORY, EQUIPMENT FROM INVENTORY";
            }
            else
            {
                sqlcommand = "SELECT SAPNO, PARTNO, PARTDESC, MINQTY, QOH , CATEGORY, EQUIPMENT FROM INVENTORY WHERE SAPNO = '" + Session["SAPNOIR"] + "'";
                Session["SAPNOIR"] = null;
            }

            DataTable dt = GetData(sqlcommand);

            //Create a dummy GridView
            GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
             "attachment;filename=DataTable.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //Apply text style to each Row
                GridView1.Rows[i].Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
            }
            GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

            //style to format numbers to string
            string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
```

when I open the excel file, all the chinese character will become unreadable character. anyone know how I can show chinese character when export to excel file!!

I do try add encoding window 1250 in my web.config but it stil not working.
Anyone please do help. thanks

Thanks for your comment is suggestion! its much appreaciated!

Comment: Not super familiar with this process, but maybe you need to specify the correct `charset` for those Chinese characters on the line `Response.Charset=`

Comment: @CBRF23 I am really appreciate your help! I do try to set utf-8 in charset but its not working. Anyway, I have found the solution. I have posted it below! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have find out why. all the data that pass into excel must encode first or else, the computer will just pass in straight away..

add the code below then problem SOLVE!!!

```
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
```